# Is it possible to add a 'break' to an axis that plots a categorical factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am using ggplot2 to plot a mixed-design dataset in a violin plot.

The data was collected over three sessions: Baseline (collected on Day 1), Post-training (collected on Day 3) and Follow-up (collected on Day 30) and two groups: (1) Active and (2) Sham. For the sessions I have a categorical factor called 'Session' with the labels: Baseline, Post-training and Follow-up which are plotted on the x-axis. (Please ignore the rough state of the draft plot and dummy data for demonstration purposes).

[image]

```
level_order <- factor(tidied_data$Session, level = c('Baseline (Day 1)', 'Post-training (Day 3)', 'Follow-up (Day 30)'))
tidied_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=level_order, y=Amplitude, fill=Group)) +
  geom_violin(position=position_dodge(1), trim=FALSE) +
  geom_jitter(binaxis='y', stackdir='center',
              position=position_dodge(1)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "point", 
               size = 3, position=position_dodge(1), color="white") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar", width=0.3, position=position_dodge(1), color="white") +
  theme_bw() + # removes background colour 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + # removes grid lines 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank()) +  #  removes border lines
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + # adds axis lines
  labs(title = "Group x Session", 
       x = "Session", 
       y = "Amplitude")
```

I want to demonstrate to the viewer that there is a different time-course between Baseline (Day 1), Post-training (Day 3) and follow-up (Day 30), it's a 30-day scale essentially.

From previous threads I've seen that this isn't something that ggplot2 will handle well, since broken axes are generally considered questionable.

I've come across the package 'ggbreak', where you can use the function 'scale_x_break' or scale_y_break' to set an axis break on a continuous variable. This doesn't work for the three time-points, presumably as it's a categorical factor.

Can anyone recommend a way that I can 'break' the axis to demonstrate the different length of time between the three sessions, or alternatively another way I could demonstrate this to the viewer? I've thought about adding custom spacing between bars, but I can only manage to set this to the same width for each bar, not different widths between different bars.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't recommend using discontinuous for  this, but you can use facets to visually indicate small multiples. Example with a standard dataset below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, fill = factor(am))) +
  geom_violin() +
  facet_grid(~ cyl, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(strip.text = element_blank()) # Hide strip text
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>